# problem with web-mode: Symbol's value as variable is void: <html>

Tags: use-package, web-mode

I am using Emacs 24.5.1 and I seem to have a problem loading the `web-mode` package using `use-package`. I managed to narrow it down to the following `.emacs` file:

```
(require 'package)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(mapc (lambda(p) (add-to-list 'package-archives p t))
      '(("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
        ("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")
        ("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/"))) 

(package-initialize)
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))
(require 'use-package)

(use-package web-mode
   :init
   (progn
     (setq web-mode-enable-current-element-highlight t)
     (setq web-mode-enable-current-column-highlight t)
     (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.html\\'" . web-mode))
     (defun my-web-mode-hook ()
       "Hooks for Web mode."
       (setq web-mode-markup-indent-offset 2)
       (setq web-mode-css-indent-offset 2)
       (setq web-mode-code-indent-offset 2)
       (setq web-mode-style-padding 1)
       (setq web-mode-script-padding 1)
       (setq web-mode-block-padding 0)
       )
     (add-hook 'web-mode-hook  'my-web-mode-hook)
     (eval-after-load "web-mode"
       '(set-face-background 'web-mode-current-element-highlight-face "color-88"))
     )
   :ensure t)
```

When I start `emacs` with the above `.emacs` I get the message:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/mperdikeas/.emacs':

Symbol's value as variable is void: <html>

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

The backtrace with `--debug-init` is not much informative (to me at least):

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable <html>)
byte-code(\210  \210\n\210
\210\210\21\210        \210\n\210\210\f\210
\210\210\210\210\210\210\210\210\207" [<html> <head> <script type= >location\.href= </script> </head> <body> Authentication is required\. Click <a href= >here</a> to open the authentication page\. </body> </html>] 1)
require(web-mode nil noerror)
(not (require (quote web-mode) nil (quote noerror)))
(if (not (require (quote web-mode) nil (quote noerror))) (ignore (message (format "Could not load %s" (quote web-mode)))))
(progn (condition-case err (progn (setq web-mode-enable-current-element- highlight t) (setq web-mode-enable-current-column-highlight t) (add-to-list   (quote auto-mode-alist) (quote ("\\.html\\'" . web-mode))) (defalias (quote my- web-mode-hook) (function (lambda nil "Hooks for Web mode." (setq web-mode- markup-indent-offset 2) (setq web-mode-css-indent-offset 2) (setq web-mode-code- indent-offset 2) (setq web-mode-style-padding 1) (setq web-mode-script-padding  1) (setq web-mode-block-padding 0)))) (add-hook (quote web-mode-hook) (quote my- web-mode-hook)) (eval-after-load "web-mode" (function (lambda nil (set-face- background (quote web-mode-current-element-highlight-face) "color-88")))))  ((debug error) (ignore (display-warning (quote use-package) (format "%s %s: %s"  "web-mode" ":init" (error-message-string err)) :error)))) (if (not (require  (quote web-mode) nil (quote noerror))) (ignore (message (format "Could not load   %s" (quote web-mode))))))
eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/mperdikeas/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1250
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/mperdikeas/.emacs"   "/home/mperdikeas/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  #[0 \205\262  \306=\203\30\310Q\202;  \311=\204\30\312Q\202;\313\307\314\315#\203*\316\202;\313\307\314\317#\203:\320\ nB\321\202;\316\322\323\322\211#\210
                                                                         \322=\203a\324\325\326\30\327Q!\"\323\322\211#\210
                                       \322=\203`\210
                                                       \203\243\330
                                                                    !\331\232\203\243\332
     !\211\333P\334!\203}\211\202\210\334!\203\207\202\210\314\262\203\241\335
 \"\203\237\336\337
                   #\210\340\341!\210\266\f?\205\260\314\323\342\322\211#)\262\207" [init-file-user system-type delayed-warnings-list user-init-file inhibit-default-init inhibit-startup-screen ms-dos "~" "/_emacs" windows-nt "/.emacs" directory-files nil "^\\.emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" "~/.emacs" "^_emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" (initialization "`_emacs' init file is deprecated, please use `.emacs'") "~/_emacs" t load expand-file-name "init" file-name-as-directory "/.emacs.d" file-name-extension "elc" file-name-sans-extension ".el" file-exists-p file-newer-than-file-p message "Warning: %s is newer than %s" sit-for 1 "default"] 7 "\n\n(fn)"]()
 command-line()
 normal-top-level()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the installation of `web-mode` has failed. Instead of getting an elisp file, you got a user oriented HTML file telling you that you are not authorized to get the file. Try to download the file manually in order to understand what happened and why.

Comment: On closer inspection, I suspect a bug in `use-package`. It appears to not have detected the failure to download `web-mode`, instead happily storing the error message resulting from the failed download as if it were an actual elisp file.

Comment: After manually installing `web-mode` (from `list-packages`) it now works.